# How to pass parameters in bytes32[] when deploying contract

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm trying to run the first example code from this webpage
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/solidity-by-example.html

However, I'm not able to figure out how exactly am I suppose to pass the parameters to this constructor. I tried passing numbers, strings, array of numbers, array of strings, but they all gave errors as shown in the second pic. Can anyone show me the correct way to pass the arguments.

[image]

[image]

Comment: ["0x...", "0x.....", "0x..."]

Answer (score 1):

you need to give an array of bytes32 in hex like this

```
["0x...", "0x.....", "0x..."]
```

example:
proposalName -> hash(https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html)

"Test1" -> d283f3979d00cb5493f2da07819695bc299fba34aa6e0bacb484fe07a2fc0ae0

"Test2" -> 4659db3b248cae1bb6856ee63308af6c9c15239e3bb76f425fbacdd84bb15330

```
["0xd283f3979d00cb5493f2da07819695bc299fba34aa6e0bacb484fe07a2fc0ae0", "0x4659db3b248cae1bb6856ee63308af6c9c15239e3bb76f425fbacdd84bb15330"]
```